# How to deploy a C static library: header + c file or object file?

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries, libraries

I have created a small library with a few functions. It has a `.h` file and a `.c` file. Let us say it's a 'hello world'. I want to put it on my Github to make it publicly available for everyone to clone and use my functions in their C or C++ code. There are two ways I see it:

1. Put out the header and the functions code and tell everyone to `#include "library"` in their programs.
2. Put out the header (for information) and the object file `.o` and tell everyone to link it during compilation themselves.

How should I go about it? What is the preferred way or a standard in creating C/C++ libraries?

## EDIT:

Follow up question: is there a way I can prepare an installation file in my repository such that the user installs my library and can later include it as `#include <library>` without the need of putting my files in his working directory?

Comment: The .o file may only useful to folks using the same compiler and version. Provide the code and building instructions. Mind you if you have a simple C interface you might be able to get away with a dynamically linked library.

Comment: `the object file .o` - no, you can't do that. Well, you can, but it will only work on environments that are similar to yours. Everyone has different architecture, the `.o` file will be different for different environments/compiler versions/libraries etc.etc.etc. Just put .c and .h files. For many `cmake` become the standard C/C++-ish way of providing consistent code builds.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, please take a look at the follow-up I added, kind regards

Comment: Read up on the cmake build automation tool.

Comment: You should use POSIX `make`. It's portable and guaranteed to be on every system that's mostly POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will ignore the question about "preferred" since that delves into matters of opinion. Covering some pros and cons, though, is less controversial. Please do not assume that this list is exhaustive.

> 1) Put out the header and the functions code and tell everyone to `#include "library"` in their programs.

Since this is not a header-only library, it would not be enough to simply `#include` the header file. Others would need to `#include` the header file *and* compile your source file as part of their projects. In any event, this is not what is usually meant by "static library". However, it could be adequate for a "library" small enough to warrant only a single source file.

> 2) Put out the header (for information) and the object file `.o` and tell everyone to link it during compilation themselves.

Both parts of this approach are problematic. First, the header would not be merely for information; others would need to `#include` it so that their compilers are aware of your API. Second, object files (`.o`) can be compiler-specific, so this approach would be useful only for those using the exact same build environment as you. That probably narrows down the field enough to make this approach of negligible use. Still, use your own judgement.

*Since we're out of your ideas, let's move on to some others.*

**3)** *Compile your code **as a static library** (`.a` on Linux, `.lib` on Windows), then distribute the header file and the library file. Others would `#include` the header file in their code and link against your library.*

The caveat here is that the library is platform-specific. This is less restrictive than compiler-specific, but it still might mean multiple releases on your part for different platforms. There is also some onus on others to copy the library file to an appropriate directory. Newer programmers might not know which directories could be appropriate.

**4)** *Put out the header file, the source code, and a [makefile](/questions/tagged/makefile) that will enable others to compile and install your library for themselves. Then they would `#include` the header file in their code and link against your library.*

This is the least restrictive approach for your end users, but it does require a good makefile from you to be successful. That takes you into a programming world outside C and C++ (separate languages, by the way).

For other projects, a potential downside to the makefile approach is the possibility that an end user does not have a (supported) compiler installed. Fortunately, static library developers may assume their end users have compilers. :)

*Note that the point of Git is to share source code. If you consider Github to be your **primary** distribution method, then you should look at options that involve distributing the source code. On the flip side, you desire a pre-compiled option, you should consider something other than Github to be your primary distribution method.*